# Custom Pandas function for formatting

Tags: python, dataset, pandas, dataframe

My data consists of a lot of Dataframes having the format as below:

```
raw_data = {
        'subject_id': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'],
        'first_name': ['Alex', 'Amy', 'Allen', 'Alice', 'Ayoung'], 
        'last_name': ['Anderson', 'Ackerman', 'Ali', 'Aoni', 'Atiches'],
        'salary': ['2000','200000','3000','300','10000'],
        'percentage': [24,434,56,12,245]}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['subject_id', 'first_name', 'last_name','salary','percentage'])
```

> ```
> 0 1   Alex       Anderson     2000    24
> 1 2   Amy        Ackerman     200000  434
> 2 3   Allen      Ali          3000    56
> 3 4   Alice      Aoni         300     12
> 4 5   Ayoung     Atiches      10000   245
> ```

My goal is to have a custom function for formatting them to the following:
`

> ```
> 0 1   Alex    Anderson    $2,000.00       24.00%
> 1 2   Amy     Ackerman    $200,000.00 434.00%
> 2 3   Allen   Ali         $3,000.00       56.00%
> 3 4   Alice   Aoni        $300.00     12.00%
> 4 5   Ayoung  Atiches     $10,000.00      245.00%`
> ```

Examples of Dataframes I have:

`Description       A     B       C        D
School            35    1.01%   0.17%   -$139,394
Fishing           5     0.57%   0.21%   -$30,572`

`School  c   Cur         NeT     OOS     Diff
Scs     663 Med         16-EM   $360    $312
Scs_2   720 Pharmacy    16-SOP  $360    $312`

current :

```
df['salary'] = df['salary'].apply(lambda x : f"${x:,.2f}")
df['percentage'] = df['percentage'].apply(lambda n : f"{n:.2%}")
```

I know that lambda functions will do this, but I want to have a custom function **def transform:** to handle all data types and format every Dataframe that I have. My plan is to use **try and catches** to handle the datatypes. But need some help with the function.

Answer (score 1):

If all your data frame are the same ( colnames and types) you can use list comprehension to change format of your data frame.
Here is an example solution with two data frames:

```
raw_data = {
    'subject_id': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'],
    'first_name': ['Alex', 'Amy', 'Allen', 'Alice', 'Ayoung'], 
    'last_name': ['Anderson', 'Ackerman', 'Ali', 'Aoni', 'Atiches'],
    'salary': ['2000','200000','3000','300','10000'],
    'percentage': [24,434,56,12,245]}

raw_data1 = {
    'subject_id': ['1', '2'],
    'first_name': ['Jimmy', 'Kira'], 
    'last_name': ['Anderson', 'Ackerman'],
    'salary': ['2000','200000'],
    'percentage': [24,434]}

df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['subject_id', 'first_name', 'last_name','salary','percentage'])
df1 = pd.DataFrame(raw_data1, columns = ['subject_id', 'first_name', 'last_name','salary','percentage'])
```

here is a function that modifies input DF`s:

```
def transform(df):
    df['salary'] = df['salary'].apply(lambda x : f"${float(x):,.2f}")
    df['percentage'] = df['percentage'].apply(lambda x : f"{float(x):.2%}")
    return df
```

Now you can iterate over the list of your data frames and change the formating , I will also concantenate the result into one data frame, but you can keep the result in the plain list for next steps if needed.

```
#create list of dataframes 
list_of_dfs = [df, df1]
#iterate over list and concat the result 
pd.concat([transform(x) for x in list_of_dfs], axis = 0)
```

Example output:

[image]

In case if your data frames doesn't have a common column to format, you can create a mapping with column names and desired format and include it in the function like this:

```
def transform(df):
    perc_format = ['B', 'C', 'D']
    currency_format = ['D1', 'Diff']
    for col in df.columns:
        if col in perc_format:
            df[col] = df[col].apply(lambda x : f"{float(x):.2%}")
        elif col in currency_format:
            df[col] = df[col].apply(lambda x : f"${float(x):,.2f}")
    return df
```

Comment: my only concern was how will the function understand what columns to iterate on(format) and what columns to skip automatically.

Comment: @m2rik I dont think that you can do it "easy" way, since for currency and percantage formatting you can use both floats or ints, there is now way to understand what type is used for which formatting, this is why I have added function with column name mapping. If your dataframes have different names but similar column position, maybe its better to rename df to common format and then do the formatting?

Comment: Yes, that was my concern too. Iterating over this function my plan is to create different datatype functions to handle the types and then apply the conversion. Something like `format(df['salary'],integer)` where `def integer(x)` is a function to handle int datatype, similarly others for floats and str. What do you think?

Comment: @m2rik I prefer specifying lists with column names like in the example before if possible and not to mess around with lots of individual functions, but if you know ahead that each type strictly corresponds to special formatting, you can do it with custom functions.